# How onClickListener works in a listview which is not in a ListActivity?

Tags: android, android-listview

I've created a listview with its own adapter, but now I have to implement the setOnClickListener method?
Reading my manual and searching on the net I've seen that it doesnt work normally in this case, can someone explain me how to use it properly, maybe with a example?

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.gabriele.progetti;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    TextView textview;
    ListView menu;
    final static String[] Scelte = new String[] {"Una citazione a caso", "Cerca per autore", "Cerca per categoria", "Crediti"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Comincio tutti i magheggi per prendere il font e settarlo */
        AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "fonts/stilo.otf");
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textview.setTypeface(typeface);
        /* Magheggi finiti */

        menu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        //SetAdapter e non setlistAdapter perchè non sto usando ListActivity.
        // Gli passo la classe MenuAdapter con un context proprio e la stringa Scelte.
        menu.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter(this, Scelte)); 

    }


}
```

And this is my MenuAdapter.java

```
package com.gabriele.progetti;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] valori;

    public MenuAdapter(Context context, String[] valori) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(context, R.layout.activity_main, valori);
        this.context = context;
        this.valori = valori;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
         // Dico al service di Android di prepararsi ad una animazione (inflate = animare).
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // Prendo tutte le View all'interno del file XML row_modificata e le metto nella ViewAnimata.
        View ViewAnimata = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_modificata, parent, false);

        // Dichiaro un context perchè in un arrayadapter se voglio prendere un asset devo utilizzarlo per forza.
        Context context1 = context;
        AssetManager assetManager = context1.getResources().getAssets();

        TextView textView = (TextView) ViewAnimata.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, "fonts/menu.ttf");
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);
        textView.setText(valori[position]); // Assegno un testo per ogni valore presente nella stringa che passo.

        return ViewAnimata;

    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in MainActivity:

```
    menu.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Pressed " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Is the position immediately found by the method? Is this a standard snippet or works everywhere?

Comment: Yeah, position found by the method, and this works everywhere

Comment: Why had you put as context parametrer in makeText the activity key? What does it stands for?

Comment: Every Activity can be used like Context

Comment: activity in my sample - is Activity object

Comment: Solved alone, i used another way but I dont need the toast in my project. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

One comment.
It will be better to use the convert view inside the adapter and don't create a new view every time.

```
View itemView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_modificata, parent, false);
    } else {
        itemView = convertView;
    }
    //set your data here
```